# GIT (Lab): Create branch from a branch in merge request

Tags: git, gitlab

I created branch "A", and made a pull / merge request to master.

Now i have another task, that needs changes from branch A, but for some specific reason it needs to be in a new branch "B".

If a checkout B from A, and later A gets merged to master, is B still valid? Will i need to update the branch with the merge from master to require a merge request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you have a master branch `master`, and a feature branch `A` and you've raised a pull request to `master` from `A`, you have also created a new branch from `A` with name `B` but you're worried about whether you'll have to merge `master` branch to your branch `B` in case `A` gets merged. The answer is it depends if only `A` is merged then you won't have merge `master` changes in your branch `B` but if some other branch or changes gets merged in `master` then you'll have to merge those changes in your branch `B`.

Let me know if this solves your problem or you have any other queries.

Comment: Can "B" be merged into master instead of A+B? Will A become useless then?

Comment: Yes, If you create a new branch from `A`, named `B` then B contains all changes that were in `A` and may contain some additional changes. so If you directly merge `B` into master it is as if both A and B were merged.
Also if you just merged `B` branch into `master`, then yes `A` will be useless as when you'll try to merge `A` into `master` all changes made in `A` would already be present there because `B` was merged and `B` was made from `A` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the branch is valid.... the question is *how do you want the branch to look*? If you don't mind that it started from A and you don't need anything from `master`, then when you are ready push it, create a PR and it should only display changes from B (and not A, if you create the PR *after* A is merged into master).

Once A in merged into master, you can do things like rebase easily:

```
git checkout B
git rebase origin/master # that should move B to the tip of master from origin repo
```

So that you can get the updates from master

Comment: Can "B" be merged into master instead of A+B? Will A become useless then?

Comment: If you merged B into master, that would include revisions from A... at least up the point where you started working on it. In general terms it is important to keep in mind that even though B depends on A, it's a separate task. Think of this case: A is rebased on top of master. Now you have _duplicate_ revisions from the original A. Think of this other case: A is dropped and it will be remade from the grounds up. Do you still want to include those revisions from the original A as part of B?